# Finding RC output voltage to a sine input?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

So I have a simple RC series circuit with a sine input with -1 dc and amplitude A. I'm trying to find the value of the output voltage across both the R and C elements. The problem is, the sine wave constantly changes, so I can't find the voltage at 0 and infinity. The sine part will never decay away. How do I find the output voltage in these cases?

Comment: Simulate on CircuitLab.com

Comment: I'd say more clarity is warranted. What do you mean by sine changing? 0 and infinity of what? Do you want to do this physically or simulate? Also, there are multiple ways to have and rc series. Post a schematic.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: I'm guessing that 0 and infinity refers to initial conditions and final equilibrium. If the incoming forcing function is a step function, then it's easy. The juice is turned on. At first the capacitor has no voltage on it, and finally, it has all the voltage on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard lesson for understanding superposition of signals.

Think of it as two separate signals, one of DC -1V and one of AC A.

Now, without values I can only assume that it is assuming your capacitor is infinite or some such silliness for education purpose. If you put a DC value, which is a steady state(think never changing like what happens to a step/switch closing after time infinity) would the capacitor charge or would the current just continue DC forever?

Now, for the AC, it is always changing, can the capacitor ever charge up, or does the voltage just keep changing. The frequency of the sin wave determines how charged the capacitor can be with reference to your R and C values but assuming we are talking about a component with a very large value. The the capacitor just always has current passing without building up real voltage and the resistor always has that voltage drop from current on it.

Example to play with. Just open it up and it is ready to run a time domain simulation where you see the Capacitor stuck at a DC value and the resistor with the entire AC wave on it. Make the values smaller and larger and see what happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZxig8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>